# How to access direct restircted page through valid username and password?

Tags: php, authentication, dreamweaver, restrict

I am new in php coding. I just want to access a restricted index.php page through login username and password.

My folder/file listing are...

```
root-index.php
root/admin/index.php
```

I want to access ../admin/index.php from site root/index.php through valid username and password but if I want to access ../admin/index.php through browser addressbar, it will not be accessed or show message "Direct access is denied" or show error page (404).

I have tried putting .htaccess file inside the admin folder.
 but I failed to get the ../admin/index.php and it is showing error page.

my .htaccess file contains...

```
Order deny,allow
Require valid-user
```

I tried like joomla restriction in root/admin/index.php

```
//// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

but I really don't know how to bypass the above coding so the page is dying.

Can anybody help me on this matter ?

for your kind information, I am using *Dreamweaver cs5* for coding and designing.

Comment: Is there nobody to solve my problem ?

Comment: I have completely no clue what you are actually up to. Perhaps a new try is in order, but only after reading how to ask good questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Especially, describe what you did, what the effect was that you got, and how it differed from your expectation. As I see that you did multiple things, you will have to explain all of your actions. Pay special attention to explain how you wanted to access the restricted page (which code did you use), and how you think the target file knows about the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your question, you want a 'login' link on your sites landing page for admins, which they go to and log in using their credentials, and then gain access to your admin/index.php page?

You really should just google search for a simple PHP login system ([see here](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=aapcen33aLK8NIGkZa5W0w&cp=23&gs_id=1x&xhr=t&q=simple%20php%20login%20system&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&qscrl=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=simple%20php%20login%20system&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.d2k&fp=80f032f325cc055f&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955))

But the basic ebb and flow of what you want, is on your admin index, look for $_SESION['user_session_id'], then redirect to a login.php if it's not set, get the user to log in using a form, check their credentials (please encrypt the password!) against the database, and if correct create the session and send them off to the admin/index.php page. If it's not correct, send them back to the login form, telling them that the credentials were wrong.

I'm not sure exactly what you were asking as it's not incredibly clear, but that's the basis of what I surmised from your question and should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I've got my answer from google. Besides, just two answers in two days...two days are very long time form me. I am a very small and simple programmer wants to know php coding. Thanks **@Lukey** for atleast understanding my simple question...